# Cannot load the desktop after adding Chinese input method

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, ibus, fcitx

I have a problem which looks very similar to the problem described in this Discourse thread: [Problems to add Chinese layout to Ubuntu 18.04](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/problems-to-add-chinese-layout-to-ubuntu-18-04/8529/2)

Basically, the desktop does not load after I input the correct password. Only the purple background and the white cursor (arrowhead) is shown. And this happened after I tried to add Chinese input method. I changed IBUS to `fcitx`. In the end, I still could not type Chinese on this laptop, and in addition it does not show the desktop.

If this can be fixed by changing `fcitx` back to IBUS, I would like to do it. But how can I do it without seeing the desktop?

Comment: What happens when you boot from live media?

Comment: @David I do not understand what you mean. What do I need to try?

Comment: Using the media you created to install the OS booting from that does the computer work and run Ubuntu.

Comment: @David The problem is fixed my friend. I just needed to login in the Wayland mode and then make the changes.

Comment: Can I recommend that you make that an answer? At the bottom left of the question you will see the answer your own question thing.

Comment: @David Of course my friend.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. As described in the cited thread, you just need to login in the Wayland mode and make the corresponding changes.

To enable/disable Wayland mode, see
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Then in the login page, first choose the user. Then at the bottom right of the screen you will see a new button, by which you can choose Wayland mode.